# Is there a way to dynamically assign a country to defaultCountry in firebase phone authentication for web?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, web, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase phone authentication for web and vuejs. I want to detect the country of the user and assign the detected country as the defaultCountry in the firebaseui config.

```
signInOptions: [
            firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            {
                provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                recaptchaParameters: {
                    type: 'image',
                    size: 'invisible',
                    badge: 'bottomleft'
                },
                defaultCountry: `'${this.countryCode}'`
            }
        ]
```

Below is the method I used to successfully get the country and assign to a variable in data ()

```
created() {
    this.getDefaultCountry()
},
```

I even tried

```
defaultCountry: this.countryCode
```

If I hardcode a countryCode ('US', 'NZ', ... ), it works.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.getDefaultCountry()` is synchronous (i.e. doesn't require any database lookups, promises, etc), you should be able to use the following code, where `defaultCountry` is swapped out for a getter instead of a static value:

```
signInOptions: [
  firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  {
    provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    recaptchaParameters: {
        type: 'image',
        size: 'invisible',
        badge: 'bottomleft'
    },
    get defaultCountry() {
      // contents of getDefaultCountry here
    }
  }
]
```

If your `this.getDefaultCountry()` is asynchronous, you will instead have to show some form of loading screen while you get the value, build `signInOptions`, give it to your FirebaseUI config and then finally render it.

Comment: It was asynchronous. I got it to work. Thanks mate.